# Python file reding and splitting

Tags: python, readline, non-ascii-characters

```
file ="data.txt"
data=[]
with open(file) as i:
    data=i.readlines()    
for i in data:
        a=i.replace(".",";")
        a.split(";")
        newdata.append(a)
        print(a[1])
```

So if I know well data now is a list of strings, is it?
I want to replace the `.` with `;` and split it into a list of strings and save it.

example data.txt:

> 1. grillsütő; jó állapotú; 5000
> 2. gyerek bicikli; 14"-os; 10000

If I know well after the reading the data variable:

> [1. grillsütő; jó állapotú; 5000] //0.index
>
> [4. gyerek bicikli; 14"-os; 10000] //1.index

and what I want:

> [[1][ grillsütő][ jó állapotú][ 5000]] //0.index
>
> [[4][ gyerek bicikli][ 14"-os][ 10000]] //[1][1]:[ gyerek bicikli]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example snippet

```
str = "1;2;3;4"
parts = str.split(";")
final_array = [[e] for e in parts]
print final_array
```

output
    `[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way:

```
file = "data.txt" 
data, newdata = [], []
with open(file) as i: 
    data = i.readlines() 
for i in data:
    a = i.replace(".",";")
    newdata.append([[j] for j in a.split(";")])
print(newdata)

# [[['1'], [' grillsütő'], [' jó állapotú'], [' 5000']],   
#  [['4'], [' gyerek bicikli'], [' 14"-os'], [' 10000']]]
```

If you wish to remove unnecessary spaces around the items in the list, you could do `strip`:

```
newdata.append([[j.strip()] for j in a.split(";")])
```